# Error in creating database table in mysql using spring,hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RMS_USER_UPDATE", uniqueConstraints = { 
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "UPDATE_ID") })
public class UserUpdateData implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "UPDATE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private long updateId;


@Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = false, nullable = true)
private long userId;

@Column(name = "CNAME", unique = false, nullable = true)
private String cname;

@Column(name = "BALANCE_AMOUT ", unique = false, nullable = true)
private double balanceAmnt;
```

This is my entity class. I am not using any type of mapping, but the column **USER_ID** is common to some other tables. When I run the code duplicate column name error for **BALANCE_AMOUT** is showing.
Error is,

```
[ERROR] 2017-08-04 07:18:AM [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] 
[execute : 236] - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table RMS_USER_UPDATE add 
column BALANCE_AMOUT  double precision
[ERROR] 2017-08-04 07:18:AM [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] 
[execute : 237] - Duplicate column name 'BALANCE_AMOUT'
```

When I changed the column name of **BALANCE_AMOUT** the error is gone. Why it is like this? I didn't get the reason. Can anyone help?

Comment: maybe `RMS_USER_UPDATE` already has a column called `BALANCE_AMOUT`

Comment: no, there is only one 'BALANCE_AMOUT' column

Comment: @Jiji what type the `balanceAmnt` field was before the update? I see hibernate is updating schema

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich I just changed the column name `BALANCE_AMOUT` then it worked.

Comment: @Jiji so this `private double balanceAmnt;` was always the definition for the field in the class, right?

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich yes

Comment: @Jiji what version of MySQL JDBC driver are you using? what the dialect version? I can't reproduce the error

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich MySQL5Dialect

Comment: @Jiji Sorry, but I still can't reproduce the issue. Could you provide more details? I could even take a look at your project if you could share it